# Hibernate Evict is not evicting the object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, microservices

My scenario is to evict the object from the hibernate primary cache. so that i can get the fresh object whenever i call the same query. i have tried evict(Obj) in my call. but still i am receiving the old object. below are my code snippet

Person Object for mapping the dataSet

```
@Data
Class person{
private String name;
}
```

clearCache method used to fetch the object

```
  main(){
    clearcache()// should return person data with name rathna
    clearcache()// should return person data with name kumar, but 
                   its returning rathna again.
    
 }


 Person clearcache()
{
 List<Person> pList = session.createQuery( "select p from  Person p ");
 session.evict(pList.get(0));
 return pList.get(0);
 }
```

Not sure my implementaion is correct. it is not evicting the data object in it.

Comment: dont understand what you want to do.why the clearcache method need to make a query ? why just clear the 1st item in the result list but not the remaining ?

Comment: i wanted to make the call twice . after first call the DB entry deleted and new entry gets added. during 2nd call, old data was returned since its returning from cache. so i wanted to evict the cache for the 2nd call. so that i will get the latest data. i kept the method name clearcache just for understanding.

Comment: @KenChan.       can u please help

Comment: how many entities will be returned from that query ? So in short , you just want the `select p from  Person p` will always return the data from DB but not from the cache ?  ?

Comment: Person table has only one data object... when i call the same query 2nd time i should get different person data , becoz while doing first call the person data fetched and removed from DB and a new entry will get added. so for the 2nd time , i am expecting the latest one. but it returns the older data whic was removed in the DB. hope this will give some betetr idea  @KenChan

Comment: @KenChan  edited description for better understanding